# PHP Restart php script after EXIT?

Tags: php, exit, die

I have a php script : I put a list of website in a textarea and the php script check if websites are down or UP .
My problem : When a website is down , the script show me an error and stop working with the rest of the list :

```
Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to http://SITEDOWN.com:80 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known) in /home/checklist/public_html/checklist.php (1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code on line 109
```

when a website is down it show me this error and then the checker stop doing his work and stop all , to fix the error i made this ( i added the DIE to the script) :

```
<?php
    public function sendpacket($host,$packet,$response = 0,$output = 0) 
    {
    $ock = fsockopen($host,80);
    stream_set_timeout($ock,5);
    if (!$ock) 
    {
    echo '=> Site down<br/>'; 
    die;

}
```

then it dont show me the error but the php script  automatically stop when a website is down (It show me SITE DOWN and stop all , no continue with others sites ) 
 I want :
When a website is down , it show me "Site Down" and php script restart/CONTINUE with the following line (i use textarea , 1site per line )

Sorry for my bad english  and thanks to all memmbers who taken the time to read this

Comment: remove `die` at the end

Comment: It looks like you're not showing us all the code, considering the multiple eval() failures in your copy/pasted error.

Comment: no is not all the code , but when i remove the DIE, the script bugs and dont stop showing me this error when it cant connect to a website

Answer (score 0):

Change die to return false and write your calling script to call the function in an if statement...

```
    if (sendpacket == false) {
        echo "Fail message";
    } else {
        echo "Success message";
    }
```

Comment: hey this is php not other language sorry